# str_split - like creation of a list of items from webpage with Rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape a webpage like [this](http://examine.com/rubric/effects/view/552/Symptoms+of+Irritable+Bowel+Syndrome/all/).  I have been working with Rvest.

The page shows several biomedical literature citations.  Each citation item contains a link to the source, a table that contains some structured info, and in some cases a blockquote called "Notes" that contains some unstructured info.

I want to pull each citation and process it individually.  However the link, table, and blockquote elements for each citation are not in a single div, they simply stack on the same set of elements for the next citation.  I can't pull each element separately because sometimes the blockquote is not there, so they won't match up.

How can I solve this with Rvest?  However, after each citation there is an hr tag.  Is there any way to split the xml_nodeset class into a list of items using the hr tag?

Comment: That's my site you're scraping...

Answer (score 0):

I did this with a bit of `rvest` and some data cleaning.  Hopefully it will generalize for you:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
```

Get the url:

```
url<html('http://examine.com/rubric/effects/view/552/Symptoms+of+Irritable+Bowel+Syndrome/all/')
```

The titles of each study are kept inside `<a>` web link wrappers. Get those and clean the linebreak. Add a number of the study and put into a df.

```
selector_name<-"a"
titles<-html_nodes(url, selector_name) %>% html_text()
titles <- gsub("[\r\n\t]", "", titles)
titles <- as.data.frame(titles)
titles$studyno <- 1:nrow(titles)
```

As you point out, the content is in a table, so use the `<td>` wrapper to get info and clean linebreaks:

```
selector_name<-"td"
content<-html_nodes(url, selector_name) %>% html_text()
content <- gsub("[\r\n\t]", "", content)
```

Then clean up a bit and `match` to get the df:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(content, ncol=2, byrow=T))
df$studyno <- cumsum(df$V1=="Change of Effect")

df$title <- titles$titles[match(df$studyno, titles$studyno)]

 head(df,7)

#                  V1                                              V2 studyno
#1   Change of Effect                                       decrease        1
#2       Trial Design                                            meta       1
#3       Trial Length                                              na       1
#4 Number of Subjects                                             392       1
#5             Gender                                           mixed       1
#6   Change of Effect Decrease   (Statistically Significant, p-value        2
#7       Trial Design                                    Double Blind       2
                                                                                                                                  #title
#1 Effect of fibre, antispasmodics, and peppermint oil in the treatment ...
#2 Effect of fibre, antispasmodics, and peppermint oil in the treatment ...
#3 Effect of fibre, antispasmodics, and peppermint oil in the treatment ...
#4 Effect of fibre, antispasmodics, and peppermint oil in the treatment ...
#5 Effect of fibre, antispasmodics, and peppermint oil in the treatment ...
#6 Treatment Of Irritable Bowel Syndrome With Peppermint Oil. A Double-...
#7 Treatment Of Irritable Bowel Syndrome With Peppermint Oil. A Double-...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions. First, save the HTML code into string_input.

First, let's extract all the links (I guess they are between content= and >, otherwise you just need to change it)

```
library(stringr)
vector_links <- str_extract_all(string_input, "content=(.+?)>")
```

Each element of vector_links contains a link. Let's extract the url only.

```
char_link <- vector_links[[1]]
vector_links <- lapply(vector_links, function(char_link){
  substring(char_link, 9, nchar(char_link) - 3)
})
```